# Serialization system.object

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm trying to create a webservice to return a generic. The return class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class RenderReturn
{
    public RenderReturnStatus StatusReturn { get; set; }
    public string MessageReturn { get; set; }
    public string MessageTitle { get; set; }
    public object **ObjectReturn** { get; set; }
}
```

Where `ObjectReturn` can be an object or a list of application objects, like cars, customers, etc..

But the webservice returns the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. --->
System.InvalidOperationException: The type Environment was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
```

This is possible or method should always return specific types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
public class RenderReturn<T>
{
  public T ObjectReturn {get;set;}
}
```

That way, at run-time, you'll have a concrete type rather than just System.Object.

Comment: virtual -1. This will not work. Generics do not work without `XmlInclude` or `KnownType`

Comment: If I create an XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType<int>)), that seems to work for me. That's explicit though, and it's been awhile since I've used XML serialization, so in a web instance, you may be correct.

Comment: Yes. So you are hard-coding the `SomeType<int>` using the KnownType anyway - you might as well define the property as `SomeType<int>`

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly name your types. Otherwise one can put something in that isn't serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Type of `object` is too generic for .NET to know what kind of object it is dealing with and how to deserialise. So it asks you to give it some hint by using `XmlInclude` attributes telling .NET the types to expect. In WCF you do the same: you use `KnownType` attribute to decorate properties.

Type `object` is not a good candidate for DTO objects that need to cross process boundaries.

In WCF or Web Services, try not to think in object-oriented fashion but think in WSDL. As far as WSDL is concerned you have a **contract** which explicitly defines the type of messages passed between client and server.